# Welcome Message - TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, quick.db

I Am Trying To Make A Welcome Message With My Discord.js Bot
I Keep Getting `user is not defined` while trying to get the bot to mention the new user

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async (message, member) => {

const welcomechannel = db.fetch(`welcomechannel_${message.guild.id}`)
// When new user joins, wait a few minutes, and if they haven't managed to get a role yet, DM them
client.channels.cache.get(welcomechannel).send(`New member joined: ${member.user.tag}`);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `guildMemberAdd` event does not have a message parameter

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async (member) => {
const welcomechannel = db.fetch(`welcomechannel_${member.guild.id}`)
client.channels.cache.get(welcomechannel).send(`New member joined: ${member.user.tag}`);
});
```